# ¿Como se elimina en colección TreeSet utilizando Iterator?

Tags: java

He hecho lo siguiente:

```
Iterator it = tree.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
  Object o = it.next();
  Asignatura p = (Asignatura) o;
  if(p.getNombre().equals(nombre))
  {
    tree.remove(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: David: bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Qué errores te da este código? ¿Qué hipótesis tienes? Dale a [edit] para aportar más información al respecto, tal y como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Usa el `Iterator` para eliminarlo:

```
it.remove();
```

No hace falta pasarle el objeto a eliminar, úsalo sin argumentos y te elimina el objeto actual (que es el que quieres eliminar). Funciona en bucles también, es una de sus ventajas.